# why does does multi readers performance in SQLite degrade when using multiple connections instead of one serialized?

Tags: multithreading, performance, sqlite

When doing SELECT which returns more than 1 row concurrently on a number of reader threads, I see that using multiple connections (connection per reader thread) is worse than those of using only one connection for all (in SERIALIZED mode).

I have a database table on a ram disk with 6 INTEGER columns, column[0] is PRIMARY KEY.
I have 10000 entries. all 5 columns are filled with random numbers using rand().
I have 50 reader threads, each doing 50 iterations of:
SELECT * FROM tbl ORDER BY

Test cases are:
1. one connection (SERIALIZED mode)
2. 50 connections (still in SERIALIZED mode)
3. 50 connections (MULTI THREADED mode)

What seems strange is that performance of (2) and (3) are poorer than those of (1).
(2) took about 3 times as (1), and (3) took 4 times as (1).
The average iteration time was significantly higher and so does the longest iteration time.

The only suspicious clue I have is that in (1) the total amount of system calls time (strace -c) was negligible, but in (2) and (3) nanosleep took 99% of the time.

does anyone have a clue as to why is that?

Comment: Can't really answer the question, but nanosleep hints at lock contention... just a guess though